# Electron-dl use promise.all for multiple simultaneous downloads

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using [Electron-dl](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl#use-it-manually)
As per [documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl#use-it-manually) 
download function `download(window,URL,Options)` accepts only url
and returns promise

**Objective:**

1. I want to download array of files simultaneously
2. in `then ()` I want to get dl.getSavePath() paths for given array
3. in  `catch()` I want to get errors for failed items for given array
4. Could  promise.all do this job ? Any other alternative ?

**What is wrong with code:**
`then()` is being called immediately instead of waiting for all downloads to finish

**Zip File:**

[electron-dl-multi.zip](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl/files/2165462/electron-dl-multi.zip)
to use `npm install && npm start`

**Big_array_test:**

```
  var files = [
    'https://download.filezilla-project.org/client/FileZilla_3.34.0_win64-setup_bundled.exe',
    'http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty-0.70-installer.msi',
    'http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test10Mb.db'
  ]
```

**Code:**

```
var files= [
'http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db', 
'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png'];
      var promises = [];
      var _browserWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
      //
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        promises.push(download(_browserWindow, files[i], {
          directory: os.tmpdir() // Default is User's downloads directory
        }).then(function (dl) {
          return dl.getSavePath();
        }).catch(function (err) {
          return err;
        }));            
      }
      Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function (_files) {
          console.log(_files);
        }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log( err);
        });
```

Comment: if you catch the errors before `Promise.all`, you somehow swallow the possible errors, are you sure there aren't any errors ?

Comment: @YoukouleleY For me , main problem is that then is not waiting for all downloads to finish. Let me make test sample somewhere

Comment: attached zip file

Comment: I think  Electron-dl  promise is wrong some how ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code is OK - except as what is said in comments, maybe you should not catch the error in `promises.push` but instead just do it in `Promise.all`.

I ran the app from your zip, and it worked and downloaded the 2 files correctly.

But then I tried to change some URL and put one that does not exist : well here's the problem. In this case `download` function does not resolve the promise (which is normal) neither rejects it (which it should).

Try it yourself running this simple code :

```
download(mainWindow, 'https://nothing.wrong-url.org', {
  directory: os.tmpdir() // Default is User's downloads directory
}).then(function (dl) {
  console.log(dl.getSavePath());
}).catch(console.error)
```

The promise is just hanging here and does not resolve nor rejects. You might open an issue on electron-dl Github.

Comment: But If you use file like 10mb , then () is called way early than waiting for downloads to finish. Can you plz verify that

Comment: @django i noticed that too, and in the final array the two names are the same, it looks like this `download` function malfunctions